# ¿Por qué el usuario registrado no está autenticado en Firebase? ¿Por qué el usuario no puede agregar productos a la base de datos Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom, firebase-auth

¿Qué debo agregar a mi proyecto para que el propietario autenticado pueda agregar productos o modificarlos?

¿Qué debo hacer para que el usuario registrado pueda agregar productos al catálogo desde el Panel de Administrador?

Tengo una aplicación que creo con npx create-react-app my-app la aplicación web que es un panel de administración para los productos de un restaurante, tienda o vendedor ambulante.

En él, el propietario de la empresa agrega productos a la base de datos de Firebase, que luego se pueden ver desde una aplicación móvil a través de este Panel de administrador.

Para aumentar mis conocimientos, he seguido proyectos y tutoriales para agregar el registro requerido del usuario a la aplicación (Panel de administrador)

Finalmente logré crear una pequeña aplicación de registro de usuario con firebase, puedes verla en este repositorio de GitHub : https://github.com/miguelitolaparra/react-firebase-email-login

Con los mismos componentes que en la App react-firebase-email-login he creado un sistema de registro en el Panel de Administrador y todo funciona, puedes ver en el siguiente enlace que subí la App a un servidor:

http://restaurantcliente.webapplicationdeveloper.es/

Esto debe ser desde donde el dueño de la empresa administra sus productos, agregando o quitando del catálogo.

Para evitar que alguien se registre y modifique el catálogo del propietario, elimine la parte SignUp y registre al usuario de la base de datos de Firebase.

Cambie las reglas de Firebase para estar seguro de la siguiente manera:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match / databases / {database} / documents {
    match / {document = **} {
      allow read: if true
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}
```

El problema ha ocurrido cuando intento agregar nuevos productos desde el Panel del Administrador, ya que los productos no se agregan a la base de datos. Cuando cambio las reglas, para que cualquiera pueda leer y escribir, funciona y el administrador puede agregar productos a la base de datos desde el Panel de administrador.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match / databases / {database} / documents {
    match / {document = **} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

He visto varios ejemplos y tutoriales de uso de rutas privadas y otros componentes, pero siempre me encuentro con problemas para añadir esos sistemas a mi proyecto, debido a los nuevos cambios react-router-domy react-routerque se han eliminado elementos como , createHistory, etc.

No sé cómo hacer que mi proyecto sea seguro y cuando el usuario está registrado, puedo agregar elementos al catálogo desde el panel del Administrador, sin agregarlos manualmente desde la base de datos.

No sé qué más hacer, después de probar con ejemplos que encontré en GitHub y no lograr el objetivo. No puedo agregar todos los ejemplos, ya que he probado al menos 30 proyectos diferentes. ¿Qué debo agregar a mi proyecto para que el propietario pueda agregar productos o modificarlos?

¿Qué debo hacer para que el usuario registrado pueda agregar productos al catálogo desde el Panel de Administrador?

Muestro algunos de los archivos

**Archivo App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router"

import firebase, { FirebaseContext } from "./firebase"
//import { auth } from 'firebase'
import firebaseObj from "./firebase"
import Ordenes from "./components/paginas/Ordenes"
import Menu from "./components/paginas/Menu"
import NuevoPlato from "./components/paginas/NuevoPlato"
import Sidebar from "./components/ui/Sidebar"
import Signin from "./components/Signin"

const auth = firebaseObj.auth

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      const user = {
        uid: userAuth?.uid,
        email: userAuth?.email,
      }
      if (userAuth) {
        console.log(userAuth)
        setUser(user)
      } else {
        setUser(null)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [])

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <div className="md:flex min-h-screen">
        <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
          <Signin />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <FirebaseContext.Provider
        value={{
          firebase,
        }}
      >
        <div className="md:flex min-h-screen">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
            <Routes>

              <Route path="/" element={<Ordenes />} />
              <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
              <Route path="/nuevo-plato" element={<NuevoPlato />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>

      </FirebaseContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App


        **Archivo Signin.js**


import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import firebaseObj from '../firebase/firebase'

const auth = firebaseObj.auth

const Signin = () => {
  const emailRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);
  const signUp = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      emailRef.current.value,
      passwordRef.current.value
    ).then(user => {
      console.log(user)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
  const signIn = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      emailRef.current.value,
      passwordRef.current.value
    ).then(user => {
      console.log(user)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center mt-10">
      <div className="w-full max-w-3xl">
        <h1 className="my-8 text-yellow-600 text-lg font-bold text-center text-7xl"> My humble restaurant </h1>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <form action="">
            <h1 className="text-center m-3">Start the Work Session</h1>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="nombre">Email</label>
              <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                ref={emailRef} type="email" placeholder="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="nombre">Password</label>
              <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                ref={passwordRef} type="password" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-400 w-full mt-5 p-2 text-white uppercase font-bold"
              onClick={signIn}
            >
              Log In
            </button>
            <div className="mb-4 mt-8 ">
              <h2 className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 text-3xl">Enter the administration panel of your restaurant and start preparing dishes and orders</h2>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Signin
```

**Archivo package.json**

```
{
      "name": "restaurantcliente",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "homepage": "/build", 
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "firebase": "^7.19.0",
        "formik": "^2.2.9",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-firebase-file-uploader": "^2.4.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
        "yup": "^0.32.9"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
        "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "build:css": "postcss src/css/tailwind.css -o src/css/main.css",
        "watch:css": "postcss src/css/tailwind.css -o src/css/main.css"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
        "history": "^5.0.0",
        "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
        "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7"
      }
    }
```